# Editor de texto para formatação de email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wysiwyg

Preciso criar uma página para criação e formatação de e-mails.

Qual editor de texto é mais confiável para fazer isso?

Digo isso devido a alguns visualizadores de e-mails serem bem limitados e não interpretarem algumas tags HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz algo do tipo em um sistema meu usando o [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). É o editor com a maior fidelidade possível entre o que aparece no editor e no e-mail efetivamente enviado.

[O CKEditor tem pacote NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CKEditor/).

Comment: Valeu Cigano, seus emails enviados ficaram com uma visualzão boa?

Comment: Fica normal. Parece uma página Web mesmo.

Comment: já coloquei no projeto, vamo q vamo..